# Linq equivalent to SQL LIKE [a-f]

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name 'LIKE [a-f]%'

How Can I acheive this in Linq??

In other words in linq how can i select all Names between a and f??

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a helper class called [SqlMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx) in the `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient` namespace that provides a `Like` method that emulates the SQL LIKE statement.

Your query would be:

```
var query = from c in Customers
            where SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, "[a-f]%")
            select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use C# Regex class to match records:

```
var selectedCustomers = from customer in customers
               where Regex.Match(customer.Name, "^[a-f].*$").Success
               select customer;
```

Comment: That cannot be tanslated into a SQL query by LINQ to SQL